# CapacitorJS not serving root index.html for angular application

Tags: angular, angular-router, capacitor

I'm using CapacitorJS to turn my Angular web application into a mobile app.
However, I have an issue.

**These are the devices I've tested this on:**
Pixel 4a emulator (Android 11),
iPhone XR (iOS 15),
Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 (Android 11)

**Version(s):**
@angular/core, router 13.0.2
@capacitor/core, android, ios 2.4.0

**Repro:**

1. I open my app
2. Javascript files are taken from /
3. I click a button to navigate to /example
4. Javascript files are still taken from /
5. I set the phone to sleep mode and wait (until js file need to be loaded again on app launch)
6. I unlock the phone again
7. Javascript files are taken from /example

**Expected behavior:**
Application javascript is taken from /

**Actual behavior:**
Application javascript is taken from /example (where it does not exist because /example is an Angular route)

Has anyone else experienced this issue, or have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Soved**
The issue was I was that I had `./` as baseUrl instead of `/` for angular :(